# How to enable 60 fps in Alice Madness Returns?

Tags: steam, alice-madness-returns

I heard that the PC version of the game is [locked by default on 30 fps](http://youtu.be/gizVo7bOcF8?t=4m2s) (max).
But there is a way to unlock that flaw.

However, I didn't find a proper instructions for that anywhere I've looked.
Is it still like that on the steam version? or I shouldn't consider about it anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a file named "DefaultEngine.ini" where you can change the max frame rate. Here is a link to the tutorial: http://steamcommunity.com/app/19680/discussions/0/846958634256504815/

**EDIT**
I apologize for the confusion, for the PC version, the file path will be a little different. Here is a quick explanation:
http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/958267-alice-madness-returns/59480931

Comment: Is there a limit to the fps that I chose to enter?
My graphics card can run it for much more than 60, so should I be afraid from game crash if I type 120-140 etc?

Comment: Not many games run higher than 60fps because most tvs and monitors can't display such frame rate. Unless you have a monitor than can output the desired frame rate, you will be using up GPU for extra frames. They say the human eye can't detect more than 60 frames anyway.

Comment: @TylerDood That's not true. The way the human eye detects light is far too complex to describe in terms of frames per second. And besides, I can certainly tell the difference between a 120Hz and a 60Hz monitor.

Comment: That's what they say. I wasn't meaning to claim that as truth or not. Just refer back to my original statement(:

Comment: https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Alice:_Madness_Returns#High_frame_rate

Comment: Rather than rely on an external link, you should provide the answer yourself.